# Sending an array with ajax to Java on AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jquery

I am currently using Java on AppEngine.

I have an array of strings in javascript. I would like to send this array to the server using jQuery and the `ajax()` function.

How can I send the array so that on the Java server side I will be able to convert it to a `List<String>` instance?

---

EDIT:

In the client side I've used this code (jQuery):

```
      var namesArray = []
      namesArray[0] = "a"
      namesArray[1] = "b"
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/ajax/someURL",
          data: {
              namesArray: namesArray
          }
      });
```

When I debug the server side I can see that HttpServletRequest instance _parameters is:

```
{namesArray[]=[a,b]}
```

But when I use `req.getParameter("namesArray[]")` it returns me the string "a"... Like stated above, my goal is to get a List of strings (`List<String>`) containing both "a" and "b".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not too sure about the Java side of things, but if you want to pass the javascript array to the server as an array encoded in a POST variable, you could do:

```
var myarray = ['Element 1', 'Element 2', 'Element 3'] ;
var dataobject = {
    postvar: myarray
} ;
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url.of/your/server/code',
    data: dataobject,
    type: 'POST'
}) ;
```

The POST variable in this case would be 'postvar'.

Comment: Thank Gus... but my biggest problem is translating this into a List of String in Java :/

Comment: Can't you just call `req.getParameter("namesArray")`, i.e. without the '[]' ?

Comment: Just looked it up - it looks like you can call `getParameterValues` instead of `getParameter` for arrays. I'm not sure what format this will return though.

Comment: Genius! It works, don't understand how I missed that function. THANKS!